# Delete Row from TableAdapter?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I have to Delete one row from datagridview which is connected to database SQL but i dont know how to call method in `Button_click(Delete)`.(ex. `this.nameTableAdapter.DeleteQuery()` ).
[image]

Error show: _ID, _KlID does now exist ??
And Sql Query is :

DELETE FROM Artikulli
WHERE (ID = @_ID) AND (KlID = @_KlID) OR
        (ID = @_ID) AND (KlID = @_KlID)

Answer (score 6):

In your `DataSet` right click the `TableAdapter` then `AddQuery` and define your delete query. Then you can call the delete method via your table adapter.

[image]

Then

[image]

Now write your query, (**use query builder if it is complicated**).

**Notice:** your parameter names are prefixed with `@`. here I have one parameter named `@Id`

[image]

Comment: Yes i did that, but i dont know how to call in button, when i click in button(delete) to delete row ? @Hossein Narimani Rad

Comment: @MandarinaPortokalli write your SQL delete query if possible.

Comment: DELETE FROM Artikulli
WHERE        (ID = @_ID) AND (KlID = @_KlID) OR
                         (ID = @_ID) AND (KlID = @_KlID)

Comment: @MandarinaPortokalli I don't see your SQL query. How many parameter should you have (I think you have not make the query string in the wizard properly, because you need 3 parameter but I guess you need 1 parameter named `ID`)?

Comment: DELETE FROM Artikulli
WHERE (ID = @_ID) AND (KlID = @_KlID) OR
      (ID = @_ID) AND (KlID = @_KlID)
Look i have 2 parameters(ID and KlID)

Comment: @MandarinaPortokalli I don't understand your query. Anyway to call the delete method you should create an instance of your `TableAdapter` then call the delete method (you have specified its name in the wizard) and pass the required parameters to it.

Comment: Ok thenks anyway from you :)

Comment: This is great. The one thing that is missing is to change the Properties on your new Table Adapter so that the bind variables match what is written in the SQL string.