# Delete button not performing its expected function i.e to delete a record in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, button

I coded a save button and a delete button. They delete records in a vb.net project that is connected with a Microsoft Access database file. The save button functions well but the delete buttons does not function as expected. If I press the delete button a message box pops up to ask me whether I am sure to delete the record or not. If I click no button the record is not deleted as expected and it returns back to the form but if I click the yes button it does not delete the record which is not as expected. There are no errors with the code.

```
 'to save record
Private Sub btn_save_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_save.Click
    Try

        Dim result = MsgBox("Do you want to save the selected record?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
        If result = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            Me.Validate()
            Me.Purchases_fileBindingSource.EndEdit()
            Me.Purchases_fileTableAdapter.Update(Me.TNJ_Retail_Management_SystemDataSet.Purchases_file)
            MsgBox("Record saved!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            'refresh data
            Me.Purchases_fileTableAdapter.Fill(Me.TNJ_Retail_Management_SystemDataSet.Purchases_file)
        Else
            'No button was pressed
            'Do nothing
            Return
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        'something went wrong :
        MsgBox("Unable to save data into the database.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)

    End Try
End Sub
'to delete record
Private Sub btn_delete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_delete.Click
    Try
        Dim u = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete record?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
        If u = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then

            'refresh data
            Me.Purchases_fileTableAdapter.Fill(Me.TNJ_Retail_Management_SystemDataSet.Purchases_file)
        Else
            'No button was pressed
            'Do nothing
            Return
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        'something went wrong: 
        MsgBox("Unable to delete data in the database.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Seems a little off to me, are you sure you should be using the table adaptor fill command to delete records?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete Row from TableAdapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763070/delete-row-from-tableadapter)

Comment: You need to Delete the row from the Table TNJ_Retail_Management_SystemDataSet.Purchases_file and then "Save" as you need to perform another Purchases_fileTableAdapter.Update to Delete the row from the database,